# Regex for certain numbers with decimal point

Tags: regex

I am new at using the regex.
I want to allow strings with following format:

(Any number of digits).(two digits after .)

e.g. 11.34, 111.78, 132323.78

Can anybody please help me in this?

Comment: 111.789 is not valid according to your regex specification.

Comment: You mean "two or more digits after"?

Comment: When you say "any number of digits", does that mean `.01` is acceptable?

Comment: corrected example. Yes Tim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be `\d+\.\d\d`

`\d` means any digit

`+` means one or more

`\.` means a literal dot.

**EDIT**
if you actually mean "two or more digits after" as Mu Mind suggests try the following:

`\d+\.\d\d+`

Answer (score 1):

```
\d+\.\d\d
```

That will match 1 or more digits, then a dot, then 2 digits. (those last two digits must exist in this case.

Fixed: Extra dot

Comment: I think you have an extraneous dot in `\d.+`